# next.js swr I do not want to execute it only at the time of initial drawing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, swr

Development Enviroment
・ next.js
・ typescript
・ swr

it uses swr to communicate with swr.
I want to run it only when the value of the query is changed.
but is also executed during the initial drawing.
what can I do to prevent it from running during the initial drawing?

```
export const useUserQuery = (query: string) => {
  const fetcher = (url) => {
    Axios.get(url).then((res) => {
      return res;
    });
    const path = `users/?query=${query}`;
    const { data, error } = useSWR<IUser>(path);
    return {
      data: data,
      loading: !error && !data,
      Error: error,
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

use `initalData` and disable `revalidateOnMount` then it should work as you expect.

see more in the docs: https://github.com/vercel/swr

Comment: Is there any swr function that does not load only for the first time?

Comment: I didn't understand how to use it

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you what to refeatch on variable change.
If you try this, it won't work, because even if `token` changes, SWR will still use the same key and return the wrong data.

```
useSWR('/api/user', url => fetchWithToken(url, token))
```

Instead, you can use an array as the `key` parameter, which contains multiple arguments of fetcher:

```
const { data: user } = useSWR(['/api/user', token], fetchWithToken)
```

See more in [docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments)